# Export SharePoint 2010 list to MS Access

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to export SP list data to MS Access programmatically ?

Rish

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a linked table from the SharePoint list and you can execute SQL against it.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/publish-a-database-to-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131469.aspx

Comment: Thanks Pleun, but I am trying to export data from SPGridView.